# NLP to analyse requests

Tags: nlp, data-science, data-analysis

Hi I am trying to analyse descriptions of around 30000 requests to identify common requests as the data has no tags or titles.

I’ve looked at a lot of content on sentiment analysis and I’m currently thinking I need to train a model from a small random sample to better classify the data.

Is there a better approach I should be following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering your question, I would say what you're looking for has similar solutions to sentiment analysis but is a different case.
If you want to group any documents you have 2 methods to move on with in AI.

1- Supervised Learning (Classifying)

2- Unsupervised Learning (Clustering)

In your case as there is no labeled (tagged) data, then clustering is more convenient.

You can generate the tf-idf vector and use it as the feature for each word and document in descriptions and cluster the data based on that.
Depending on the coding language you use there are a lot of examples on the web but for java you can check out below links,

[TextAnalyzer](https://github.com/sea-boat/TextAnalyzer)

[Carrot Clustering](https://github.com/carrot2/carrot2)